# How to bind a preprocessor to babel-register, to modify files before babel kicks in

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-register

I have a set of "mostly-JSX" files that if interpreted as straight up JSX contain illegal syntax. I also have a set of (synchronous) functions that can take this "mostly" JSX syntax and convert it to proper JSX syntax. These functions are currently used as webpack loaders to make sure that by the time webpack hands the data to babel, it's proper JSX.

As an example, these functions turn the following "nearly JSX" (which has JSX-conflicting LaTeX code, as well as JSX-conflicting syntax in a `<pre>` block:

```
module.exports = require('react').createClass({
  ...,
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>An example component</h1>

      <p>With latex:</p>

      <p>\[ \begin{align}
        f(t) &= t \cdot \sqrt{t} \\
        &= t^{1.5}, 0 \leq t \leq \inf
      \end{align}\]</p>

      <p>code:</p>

      <pre>function(t) {
  if (t<0) 
    return undefined;
  return Math.pow(t, 1.5);
}</pre>
    </div>);
  },
  ...
});
```

Into the following "actual JSX":

```
module.exports = require('react').createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>
      <h1>An example component</h1>

      <p>With latex:</p>

      <p><img src="images/latex/fhqo89732hf98o3h4f3.svg"/></p>

      <p>code:</p>

      <pre>function(t) {{'\n'}
  if (t&lt;0){'\n'}
    return undefined;{'\n'}
  return Math.pow(t, 1.5);{'\n'}
}</pre>
    </div>);
  }
});
```

After running the functions, the LaTeX has been parsed out and replaced with a link to its corresponding static asset image, so there is no JSX syntax conflict anymore there, and the `<pre>` element has had any conflicting characters replaced with JSX-safe html entities, and in order to preserve line breaks (because minification is the enemy of white-space), has been given explicit newlines at the end of each line.

However, in order to do some server-side page generation using Node.js I'm requiring `babel-register` so that Node can "natively" load JSX files, but this is a problem because it will see the mostly-JSX syntax and throw errors.

As basic test script I'm using the following code:

```
// register native JSX
require("babel-register")({
  // this is not sufficient to load "almost JSX" files
  // with data that needs to be preprocessed out, first.
});

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var ReactRouter = require('react-router'); // v1.0
var RoutingContext = ReactRouter.RoutingContext;
var RouteMap = require('../lib/site/routemap');
var routes = RouteMap.routes;
var paths = RouteMap.paths;

var fs = require('fs-extra');
paths.forEach(path => {
  ReactRouter.match({ routes, location: path }, (err, _, renderProps) => {
    var data = ReactDOM.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
    fs.writeFile(`./static/pages/${url}.html`, data, 'utf-8');
  });
});
```

And for clean JSX files this poses no problems, but for files that need preprocessing, this causes Babel to throw a terminal error. So:

Is there a way to tell `babel-register` to run preprocessors over the files that node is being asked to load in with `require(...)` calls?

I've read through the babel docs but I can't seem to find any section on preprocessing; there are plugins, but these kick in *after* Babel has already parsed files into ASTs, and the almost-JSX syntax makes Babel error out while trying to build an AST.

Alternatively, is there a way to hook into Node's own file loader so that if it's being asked to load js/jsx files, I can run my preprocessors *first* and then tell node to pass the transformed data on to whoever handles these filetypes (in this case `babel`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by setting up your own require hook that comes before Babel's. I'd take a look at [Pirates](https://github.com/ariporad/pirates), which I think is designed to make it easier to set up require hooks that will interoperate with other modules that setup require hooks. There's a [proposal to use it in Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3139). It's `README` gives an illustration of how to set one up "manually". Perhaps it'll be useful for setting up what you need, or perhaps just the illustration in the `README` will prove useful.

Comment: Giving that a go atm, it looks like `pirates` has an [interesting bug](https://github.com/ariporad/pirates/issues/15) but if that can be solved, it looks like it might be part of the solution to this problem.